# Pantone/CMYK color book guide?

Tags: color, cmyk, pantone

I am a graphic designer and I wanna buy a Pantone colour guide book, the pair one for coated and uncoated colours which compares the Pantone color with its CMYK version?Any advise which pait is the best? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42452/pantone-bridge-books-uncoated-vs-coated and http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/53064/which-pantone-book-should-i-get

Answer (score 0):

The Bridge formula guide show the Pantone next to the CMYK equivalent.